# Retrieve Private Ip address of API management using azure Cli

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-cli

I am trying to read private ip address of api management on console using azure cli command but  output is coming as blank none of the below command is working -
az apim show -n  -g  --query "networkConfigurations[0].privateIpAddress[0]"
az apim show -n  -g  --query "privateIPAddressesConfiguration[0].privateIpAddress"
Does anyone know If the command is correct if not please share the correct command

Tried running the below commands -

```
az apim show -n <name> -g <group> --query "networkConfigurations[0].privateIpAddress[0]"
az apim show -n <name> -g <group> --query "privateIPAddressesConfiguration[0].privateIpAddress"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to read private ip address of api management on console using azure cli command but output is coming as blank.

You need to use **privateIpAddresses** instead of **privateIpAddress** in your query as if you will run simply `az apim show -n <name> -g <group>` command, you will see the parameter name is **privateIpAddresses**.

You can use any of these queries to get the private IP address of APIM.

```
az apim show -n <APIM_Instance_Name> -g <Resource_Group>  --query "privateIpAddresses"
or
az apim show -n <APIM_Instance_Name> -g <Resource_Group>  --query "privateIpAddresses[0]"
or
az apim show -n <APIM_Instance_Name> -g <Resource_Group>  --query "privateIpAddresses" -o tsv
```

**Output**

[image]